Recargar código JavaScript en Thymeleaf
Trabajo con Spring - MVC, Thymeleaf y Datatable.net
El problema que tengo es que cuando pongo la vista en el index en el main que acepta vistas dinámicas me parece no está cargando el JavaScript que viene en la vista que se inyecta
Tengo lo siguiente en el index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Awesome - Main</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Contenido del sidebar -->
      <h2>Menú</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="a" href="#" onclick="loadView('/listGyms')">Gym</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="#" onclick="loadView('/listObjetivos')">Objetivo</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <main id="main-content" class="main">
      <p>Contenido inicial en el main</p>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script>
    async function loadView(url) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Error al cargar la vista');
        }

        const data = await response.text();
        document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = data;
      } catch (error) {
        document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = '<p>Error al cargar la vista</p>';
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>

Tengo lo siguiente en index-gym.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

    <!-- Datatables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />

    <!-- Datatables JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <!--/* Per-page placeholder for additional links */-->

    <script th:src="@{/js/prueba.js}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="text-center">Soy Gym</h2>

    <table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011-03-09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009-12-09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008-12-16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010-02-12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009-02-14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008-12-11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008-09-26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011-02-03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011-05-03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009-08-19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013-08-11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009-07-07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009-02-27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010-07-14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008-11-13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011-06-27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011-01-25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>


</body>

</html>

Espero que salga así

Pero esta saliendo así

El problema es que cuando inyecto el html dinamico no se esta cargando el javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});


El problema con el script es que se añadió a la página una vez que el DOM ya había cargado, por lo que jQuery no logra encontrar las tablas,

Finalmente pude resolver el problema uno de los problemas era que estaba renderizando las vistas con javascript y al cambiarlo con jquery funciono
Función con JQuery
<script>
    async function loadView(url) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
          $('#main-content').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
          $('#main-content').html('<p>Error al cargar la vista</p>');
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

También tuve que poner las dependencias en orden y version de jquery que me estaba dando problemas en el index
<!-- Datatables JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

